# weird activity behaviour

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I'm new to android and I'd like to develop simple game.

I have read about the Activity lifecycle on [the official android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) and also  here on stackoverflow, but I need a little help with pausing/resuming the game :-/

I had expected some scenerio similar to the lifecycle diagram, but when I lock the screen, method `Activity.onDestroy()` is also called, but then `onCreate()` is called again. I am confused as `onRestart()` is not being called!

I know about the problem with screen orientation, and have added `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` which was supposed to help.

I'm happy with the other game mechanics such as animating, colisions etc, which are well described on the internet, but I can't manage pausing/resuming.

Could someone recommend a comprehensive tutorial or give a code example? Anything covering how to build the skeleton of simple game, which can be paused, saved, etc would be much appreciated.

thanks a lot

Comment: After a new create, you should not be expecting a restart, only a start.  To prevent the gratuitous destroy/create cycle, you need to handle orientation changes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try manage game threads from activity that`s call game, surfaceView or something... with some public methods in threads, pause & resume them. Use these methods in activity onResume(), also  in onPause().
Also can try to stop threads when pause game, and when resuming - create a new threads and start them.